# System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") returns null using AVD

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio 1.5 on Windows 7.  I created an AVD emulating a Nexus_5_API_21.  I specified an SD card of 2 GB.  I have copied a file to the SD card.  Why is null returned from System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")?

I am sure you must realize by now how green I am.  Here is an additional fact.  This code works on a real phone with files on an SD card.

Comment: Since there is no documentation stating that such an environment variable exists on Android, why would you expect it *not* to be `null`? Besides, the AVD's "SD card" models [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare Although there is no documentation on `SECONDARY_STORAGE` it is used in framework: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java#L1404-1411 It is also used in many popular file manager apps.

Comment: I'm assuming the SD card is actually internal storage (not a removable SD). You should use `Environment.getExternalStorageDir()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
String strSDCardPath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
if ((null == strSDCardPath) || (strSDCardPath.length() == 0)) {
    strSDCardPath = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_SDCARD_STORAGE");
}
```

also read this for reference:
http://pietromaggi.com/2014/10/19/finding-the-sdcard-path-on-android-devices/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.
try it...

First get All files in list

```
var file=new Java.IO.File("storage/");
var listOfStorages=file.ListFiles();

var isSDPresent=false;

if(listOfStorages[1].Name.Containes("emmulated")
||listOfStorages[0].Name.Containes("-") )
{
   isSDPresent=true;
}
```